# calling run method without starting a new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

please, what will be the outcome if i implement a code like this

```
public class MyName implements runnable {
    Thread t;
    boolean checkinstance_state = false;

    /*then in a method somewhere in the class i have something like this*/

    public void firstOperation {
        /*do something and then call setBlah()*/
        setBlah();
    }

    public void setBlah(){
        if(checkedinstance_state){
            t = new Thread();
            t. start();
            checkedinstance_state = true;
        } else {
            t.run();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        /*another method operation here*/
        setBlahBlah();
    }
}
```

Bearing in mind i am already implementing a runnable. Case is, i will keep accessing this class periodically, and i don't want to be creating a thread object all the time. so i want a situation that if a thread object has been created already, the run method should be called instead. is this a correct thing to do and will there issues involved, that i can't foresee in this implementation? Thank you.

Comment: how did the "try" get in there

Comment: oops sorry, i was writing the code as i was posting. so i did not think too much. will change it. :)

Comment: The first thing that will happen is that you will be arrested for violating Java naming conventions.  Then you will get a compilation error.

Comment: @StephenC haha.. ok, i will edit the question. as i said, i was writing the code as i was posting. so i did not think too much of it. by the way, i thought "threadtry" would be ok since its joined together. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not do what you want it to do. Create an executor service, and pass instances of the runnable to the executor on a regular basis; you don't want the class to do its own thread management, nor do you want to manage the threads yourself. The executor services were designed to isolate you from the thread processing.

Comment: Joseph is correct, you should just be posting a Runnable to the Global Handler.  Or possibly the AsyncTask thread.

This wont even run since the inner instantiation should die giving out that a Looper was not initiated.

Comment: Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: the class actually extends a service too. i made the question that way, so it could be as generic as possible as some might not be android inclined. so do i still need an ExecutorService? In my case, both methods are blocking operations where as one method ends, it calls the second method. i do one method in a service and then do the second in a thread.

Comment: Well, if the first method is blocking, you wouldn't need a thread for it - that's what threading would change. But the second method call would take place in an executor, on first glance at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the run() method, but the code will run in the current thread where you call the method, not in the thread instance (t) as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you should have the if condition as

```
if(!checkedinstance_state)
```

because with your code the thread object will not at all get initialized.

So that for the first time Thread object will be initialized and started, and JVM will run the run method by itself when the threaed objects enters the `runnable` state. and from then on whenever you call the `setBlah()` then the `run` method will be called explicitly in the current thread.

Comment: thanks.. i was wondering why it kept giving me a null pointer exception on the t.run();